# How can I do a test class? for the public static List<FlowOutputs> sendEmailFromMarketingCloud(List<FlowInputs> paramOrdered)

Tags: salesforce, apex

Please help I am a beginner in creating test class if someone could give me an idea to get started.
the next class is the one to be tested

```java
public class invokeMarketingCloudTriggeredSend {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send email from marketing cloud' description='send email from marketing cloud' category='MarketingCloud')
    public static List<FlowOutputs> sendEmailFromMarketingCloud(List<FlowInputs> paramOrdered) {
        List<FlowOutputs> paramFlowOutputs = new List<FlowOutputs>();
        System.debug('param1' +paramOrdered[0].recordId+'param2'+paramOrdered[0].emailSuscriptor+'param3: '+paramOrdered[0].verificationCode);
        
        HTTP_Client client = new HTTP_Client();
        client.namedCredential = 'MCAuth';
        client.method = 'POST';
        client.auxParams = '/v2/token';
        client.body = '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"hwuh8qlr4o5mxalndl0e5k4q","client_secret":"XhsQ9lgQn7DHegdSlmFeLr3D"}';

        Map<String, String> mapHeader = new Map<String, String>();
        mapHeader.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        client.headers = mapHeader;

        HTTPResponse resp = client.call();

        Map<String, Object> mcToken = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());
        String restToken = (String) mcToken.get('access_token');

        HTTP_Client clientRest = new HTTP_Client();
        clientRest.uri = (String) mcToken.get('rest_instance_url');
        clientRest.body = '{"To":{"Address":" '+paramOrdered[0].emailSuscriptor+'","SubscriberKey":"'+paramOrdered[0].emailSuscriptor+'","ContactAttributes":{"SubscriberAttributes":{"CustomField1":"' +paramOrdered[0].recordId+'","CustomField2":"'+paramOrdered[0].verificationCode+'","CustomField3":"var3"}}},"Options":{"RequestType":"ASYNC"}}';
        clientRest.method = 'POST';
        clientRest.auxParams = 'messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:590/send';

        Map<String, String> mapHeaderRest = new Map<String, String>();
        mapHeaderRest.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        mapHeaderRest.put('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + restToken);

        clientRest.headers = mapHeaderRest;

        HttpResponse respRest = clientRest.call();

        System.debug(respRest.getBody());
        

        return paramFlowOutputs;
    }
```

Comment: Check out the resources in [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test) on Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: Btw add the tag of the language that you are using and also you can format the code properly with code fences